# How to define an event hub in Docker compose yaml?

Tags: docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric

I'm not too familiar with HLF. My predecessor, from whom I inherited his code, instructed me to deploy my Docker containers via the following commands:

```
docker stack deploy --compose-file=docker-compose-orderer.yaml fabric
docker stack deploy --compose-file=docker-compose-org1-peer.yaml fabric
docker stack deploy --compose-file=docker-compose-org1-cli.yaml fabric
docker stack deploy --compose-file=docker-compose-org1-ca.yaml fabric
```

I'm working on a callback mechanism, and apparently I need an event hub for this. I'd like to start my channel with an event hub, but I'm not sure how to define this in my Docker compose file. Can anyone provide any code samples or direct me to any resource that explains this?

Answer (score 0):

The event hub is just a service offered by the peers. You do not need to set anything in particular up, you will register the event hub in your client code using the Fabric SDK.